# Unknown characters within subject line of mail app in unix terminal

Tags: shell, email, unix

I've set up the mail app and created a shell script to FTP to a website server and then send an email to the admin. Last night it was working perfectly. I made changes to it this morning and it started sending two of the same email with different ASCII characters within the subject line.

```
#Send an email confirming update
cat /Users/rmdlp/Documents/Scripts/message.txt | mail -s “Website Update” myemail@myemail.ca
```

Here is a snippet of the email *subject* I receive:

[image]

Everything else works fine. The "message.txt" file is within the body of the message and it gets to my email OK.

Also in the sender's list this string is being added:

[image]

I also receive a "You have mail in /var/mail/$USER", which I did not receive before. I looked at that file and this is a portion of what it outputs:

```
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: "update???"

--9490A103F482.1450820767/Roys-MBP.lan
Content-Description: Undelivered Message
Content-Type: message/rfc822

Return-Path: <rmdlp@Roys-MBP.lan>
Received: by Roys-MBP.lan (Postfix, from userid 501)
    id 9490A103F482; Tue, 22 Dec 2015 16:46:05 -0500 (EST)
To: rmdlp@live.ca, Update”@Roys-MBP.lan
Subject: “Website
Message-Id: <20151222214605.9490A103F482@Roys-MBP.lan>
Date: Tue, 22 Dec 2015 16:46:05 -0500 (EST)
From: rmdlp@Roys-MBP.lan (Roy Perez)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `mail -s “Website Update”` is not doing what you think it does. `“` is U+201C, LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK, which is *not* the same thing as `"`.  Unlike `"`, `“` is not treated specially by the shell, and so the command gets split up at the whitespace in `Website Update`, resulting in a subject of `“Website` and an extra recipient of `Update”`.  This extra recipient is interpreted as `Update”@<YOUR HOSTNAME>`, but because there is no such user, the email to it gets bounced back and ends up in your mailbox.  All the "unknown characters" along the way are due to encoding issues.

This is why you use plain text editors to write code, not word processors.